# Win7 locks up when tries to sleep

Tags: windows-7

About half the time I try to make my laptop sleep (Windows 7 x64), instead it locks up and the fan suddenly gets louder at max speed.

How can I troubleshoot this to see what process or driver is the culprit?

Comment: Can you still ping the machine? Does music continue to play?

Comment: No, can't ping it.  I'm sure if music were playing it would stop. It's like all processes were put to sleep except one that is eating all the CPU  in endless loop

Answer (score 0):

I previously met the problem, and this may because the antivirus software is active when you put your computer to sleep mode.

If you installed the antivirus software, try to uninstall them.
In addition, you can perform a clean boot. After boot to your sysytem, directly put the machine to sleep mode, seeing if the problem still exists.